# Character array as json to firebase in esp32 ( arduino IDE)

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-ide, esp32

I'm using Firebase 32 Client (https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP32 ) in my project. I'm not able to use a **character array in json.set function**. I need to send the character array of 7 bytes ( made of numbers) to RTDB as json . Please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String class to create String object from char array like this.

String myString = String(myCharArray);

Use this string with the FirebaseJson function in the Firebase library.